# ubuntu 12.04 often getting freeze

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I am using linux ubuntu 12.04 since last 10 months. Now a days my system getting freeze often. I can not work frequently even for 10 mins.

**My system config:**

**Ubuntu**

Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit

Kernel Linux 3.8.0-35-generic
   GNOME 3.4.2

**Hardware**

Memory: 1.9GiB

Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G2010 @ 2.80GHz × 2

**System status**

Available disk space: 68.9 GiB

**Note 1:** I am mostly using eclipse and mozila browser in my system.

**Note 2 :** freeze in the sense my system simply stuck until press system restart button.

I dont have idea why this happen so someone please help me out.

Comment: You will need to supply us with something to go on: check log files for notices of errors. Also: boot up from the live dvd and do a memory check. Often random crashes are from bad memory.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the freeze?  Is the disk active while freezes?

Comment: @MadMike freeze in the sense that system got gang and i cant do anything even cant move cursor

Answer (score 0):

Well your cpu is not the best, try upgrading to 14.04 and see how it works. Try to install 2GB more of ram and go for the 64bit if your cpu support it. 
Install Psensor and see what you cpu usage is.

What is your graphic card?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09). this my CG

Answer (score 0):

Among other things suggested here, like adding more RAM, you could try using less resource-intensive desktop environment, like lxde or xfce, change to another display manager (gdm or kdm), and lessen the number of start-up processes.

Also, remember to clean up cache in firefox and occasionally do `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove automatically installed packages that Ubuntu no longer needs. More info in man page for apt-get. There's some interesting cleaner programs in Software Center, like BleachBit.

To change desktop environment (the appearance), refer to this post: [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

To change  to another display manager: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860704

For changing number of start-up processes  and some other extra tweaks: http://www.howtogeek.com/115797/6-ways-to-speed-up-ubuntu/

Also, this last point is somewhat opinion-based, because I can't find the article I've read before, but it said that 64 - bit OS are generally performing much better. The test was done on 1 GB old Macbook, and 64-bit OS has showed better performance. So, when you want to upgrade to new Ubuntu release, consider switching to 64 bit version. It's not that you have to use 32 bit OS with less than 4 GB or RAM,  but rather that 32-bit OS can't use anything above 4 GB, and 64-bit OS just differ in that - they can use more memory.

Occasionally, try looking into logs, see if there's any errors or crashes to troubleshoot problems. Generally you can look through /var/log directory, or through system log utility ( I personally have Ubuntu's default system log utility and installed KSystemLog , which i think is from for kde desktop ).  Also, ocasionally, look which processes use up too much cpu/memory. For that use htop, top, or system monitor utility.

Good luck !